# Jquery validation working with class but not with rules and messages

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-validate

Io have created a custom wordpress plugin and added javascripts as follows.

```
function admin_load_js(){


wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url( '/js/jquery.validate.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js1', plugins_url( '/js/oc.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );

}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_load_js');
```

my validations are not getting fired, but when i try and give class as **required and number** the validations is getting triggered.

```
<input class="required number" id="userlogin" type="text" name="user[login]" value="" size="20">
```

my validation code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#id").validate({
        debug: true,
        rules: {
            userlogin: {
                required: true,
                number:true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            userlogin: {
                required: "required!!!!",
                number:"true"
            }
        }
    }); 

});
```

the above code is not working, any ideas?

Comment: because name of your input and the rules key is not matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the input field and the rule/message keys are not matching so use

```
$('#id').validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
        'user[login]': {
            required: true,
            number: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        'user[login]': {
            required: "required!!!!",
            number: "true"
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8bxrf181/)

Comment: I know it seems logical, but don't forget to replace the ID `$('#userlogin').validate({`